# Can't select anything for build definition process tab

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I am trying to create a build definition, specified the build definition name inside the General tab, specified the trigger, the workspace, the build controller that I want to use, the drop folder as a network shared location, the retention policy but when I go to the Process tab I can't select anything. Does anyone knows why I can't select anything inside the Process tab, it looks like it is not enabled, can't press Show details because is not enabled.

Thanks!

Comment: Please could you provide a screen grab of what you are seeing, this may help us solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the root level of your project in Source Control Explorer.  Do you have a "BuildProcessTemplates" folder?

Source Control Explorer > [server] > [project] > BuildProcessTemplates

This usually contains DefaultTemplate.xaml and UpgradeTemplate.xaml.  If this folder is not present you may have to copy this folder from another project.

Comment: Yes, I do have the templates. Something else seemed to be the problem, I can't tell the cause of it.